# Latency is not identified

Tags: discord.py, latency

I was testing my code today, when suddenly an error came up saying that they could not find a reference of latency in _ _ init.py _ _. This never happened before so I don't know what to do. Here is the code of the command and the imports:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from pretty_help import PrettyHelp


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
bot.load_extension('cog_admin')
bot.load_extension('cog_stuff')
bot.load_extension('cog_info')
bot.help_command = PrettyHelp()


bot.help_command = PrettyHelp(index_title="CatsyBot Help Page", no_category="Stuff")


@commands.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    """PING PONG"""
    await ctx.send(f" Pong with {str(round(commands.latency, 2))}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commands` doesn't have the attribute `latency`, but your `bot` instance has

```py
await ctx.send(f" Pong with {str(round(bot.latency, 2))}")
```

Comment: Thanks. But why did it work before but not now?

Comment: `commands.latency` doesn't exist, and never existed. It could never work

Comment: That’s weird, it never existed so it could never work